# Iterate all item of ul and insert into database using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am new with jquery. I want to insert all the list items of ul. I tried the following but its not working can someone please guide me whats wrong with the code as i did "***async:false"*** but it still not working

```
$('#sortable li').each(function () {  
            items += $(this).text();
            insertCustomBCFields($(this).text(), plu);
        });
```

And insertCustomBCFields ftn is below

```
function insertCustomBCFields(field, plu) {
        alert(field + plu);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ProductDefinition.aspx/insertBCCustomFields',
            data: "{'field':'" + field + "', 'plu':'" + plu + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Insert Failed!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What happens? Any errors? Which of the alerts get hit? And why is your function returning "false" ?

Comment: @Stargazer Thnx for your comment.. No error occured, when i click save btn it goes back. Return false is just for testing.. Thnx for pointing me i deleted that now.

Comment: Goes back where? Also what alerts get hit? please explain more on what is not working?

Comment: @TejasKale I've sortable list on modal window when i click save btn it just disapper the modal when but not insert the record. i placed alert before ajax call it poped up but ajax call will not work

Comment: The answer provided by @dreamweiver may shed some light. Is there a possibility that the save button is simply submitting the page instead of simply invoking your javascript function? You may want to give more details on this wit some code or fiddle illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Making a ajax call with  `async: false,`  will make it synchronous call . this option should be set to true to make a asynchronous call `async: false,` unless a synchronous call is necessary.

I can see that your making call to the ajax function each time a  `li` is found in your DOM structure(now thats very bad in terms of performance), well thats not so good, instead you can make ajax call once all the items are iterated.
something like this

```
    var arr="";
    var index=0;
    $('#sortable li').each(function () {  
        items += $(this).text();
        arr+="{field"+index+":" + field + , "plu"+index+":" + plu + "}";
    });
    insertCustomBCFields(arr);
```

Similarly change the ajax call as well

```
   function insertCustomBCFields(arr) {
    alert(field + plu);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ProductDefinition.aspx/insertBCCustomFields',
        data: {'arr':arr},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Insert Failed!");
        }
    });
   }
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Just to complement, off course, your insertBCCustomFields in the above scenario should be able to correctly deal with the json data sent.